# How to exclude a tag by default but also include those tags when another tag is called?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, rspec, capybara, rspec-rails

Context: I currently have some capybara specs using `selenium-webdriver` tagged with `:qa`. I want to have these excluded when I run `rspec` by default because of the time they take to run. To do this, I have `config.filter_run_excluding :qa` in my `spec_helper.rb`. This is currently working as intended.

Desired Behavior: I would like the `:qa` tag to be excluded by default. However, I want to include all `:qa` specs when I run `rspec -t ~all`. This is currently the behavior in another app. In the other app this behavior is covered by the following.

```
unless config.filter_manager.exclusions.rules[:all]
    config.filter_run_excluding :functional_test
  end
```

For some reason, this is not working on the current app in development. The way I described above is the way it needs to work because the same behavior needs to work across apps.

Answer (score 0):

Specifying `-t ~all` says to run everything that doesn't have the metadata tag `all` on it, and sets itself in `filter_manager.exclusions.rules`. It's a strange thing to set up your tests to run all tests by telling it not to run tests with `all` metadata, but to do that you should just do the same thing as your other app.

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  unless config.filter_manager.exclusions.rules[:all]
    config.filter_run_excluding :qa
  end
end
```

If that's not working for you then you'll need to provide an example of the test so we can see exactly what metadata you're setting on it and the rest of your RSpec config so we can see what could be conflicting.